# WooCommerce Single Daily Product Arranged as Calendar View

Tags: javascript, wordpress, calendar, woocommerce

I would like to arrange my WooCommerce products (there is only one each day) in a calendar format. I feel like I could do this with JavaScript but maybe I am off base. Ideally I would want the calendar to be clickable, similar to an interactive ticket seating chart but I would be happy if I could get them laid out in a calendar grid view that auto populates as future products are added.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I used FT Calendar Plugin. Not exactly what I was trying to do but it did the job.